# How can I edit the sun reflection on a glossy objects?

Tags: rendering, animation

Hey I want edit the sun reflection, because its looks like an lamp and not a sun in the reflection.
[image]

Comment: Please be more specific about *what* you want to do. Do you want to get rid of the reflection, change the appearance (add glare, etc.) , or something else?

Comment: I think if you take real sun, get rid of its glare, glow and streaks it will likely look the same

Comment: i want to get glow from the sun on the helmet, but when I take the sun on a extra layer the reflection didn't changed.

Comment: You can turn on and off object visibility for specific rays in the properties window, you can make the sun lamp invisible to reflections